# Mysql - Left join issues in the where clause

Tags: mysql

I have two tables : activities and activity_images and the foreign key constraint is :

```
activities.id = activitiy_images.activity_id
```

Now some activities have images and some do not, which means for a particular activities.id , there might not be an entry on activity_images.

i want to fetch all the data by default , regardless of the data present in activity_images .

Below is my query :

```
select a.*,a.id as 'activity_id',b.* 
   from activities a 
   left join activity_images b on a.id = b.activity_id 
   where b.image_type='main' LIMIT 0, 9
```

The issue is with the output . The above query only gives me the data for the matching rows and where b.image_type='main'. It does not output the rows for which there is no entry in activity_images .

I want all the rows but at the same time i want to make sure that b.image_type='main' because there are other values for image_type and i just want to grab the values for image_type= 'main' (If at all there is a match) .

Please advice . Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there isn't a matching row in activity_images then how can the image_type = main?  Think about this logically.

Comment: If  ( phrased informally ) you want all rows with no activity_images and the rows with activity_images whose type is main, you have to change your where clause to `where coalesce(b.image_type, 'main') = 'main'`. If that's not your intention, cf. Devon's comment.

Comment: thats the whole point....i mean..if at all the rows match they should match for image_type= 'main' , if they dont , return them as null.Isnt that a possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When criteria in a `WHERE` clause applies to a joined table, it's basically treated as an `INNER JOIN`.

The proper way to handle this is to move the criteria into the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT a.*, a.id as 'activity_id', b.* 
   FROM activities a 
   LEFT JOIN activity_images b
     ON b.activity_id = a.id
     AND b.image_type = 'main'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...this one actually helped in many ways more than the answer accepted before.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.*,a.id as 'activity_id',b.* 
   from activities a 
   left join activity_images b on a.id = b.activity_id 
   where b.image_type='main' OR b.image_type IS NULL
 LIMIT 0, 9
```

Would this do what you want?

I would recommend image_type to be a not null column in this case otherwise you could get data that has a matching row but image_type is actually set to null.

Comment: Ohh ...i feel really stupid now . Yes , this is what i wanted. Thanks a lot Devon .

Answer (score 0):

Try a subquery. This will pre-select only the rows in your activity images table with your preferred image type, and will still select everything from your activities table:

```
SELECT a.*,b*
FROM activities a 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT * FROM activity_images WHERE image_type = 'main'
    ) b ON a.id = b.activity_id;
SELECT * FROM activity_images WHERE image_type = 'main' a;
```

Comment: Thanks @DanM - my first code post here, and formatting definitely didn't hold.